# Diagonal Wedge Shaped CSS - Edge to Edge Centered in Browser

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I have been trying to make this shape in CSS.

Ideally it will span the entire length of the browser window and probably extend outside the field of view to support larger screens and also be centered so that the angle does not change.

Anyone have any solutions?

[image]

Also I think I might run into a problem of the angle aliasing harshly.
I might need to resort to using an image. Would like to use CSS though.

** Image Spelling Error. (Indefinitely not Inevitably)

Comment: Whatever Works is fine by me.

Comment: using css 3 gradient is simple then see: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: see here for a fiddle with altered css3 gradient - note it will fallback gracefully BUT not display exactly as you want for all browsers http://jsfiddle.net/Q9pWr/

Comment: I would stick with images if you need to have it full cross browser though.. there is one other option I know of which involves some head-screw method of using bevelled edge border colours to produce triangles of any size and dimension if you MUST use css only

Comment: I've tried something like this in the past, and I don't think you're going to get nice anti-aliasing like you would with an image (especially if the angle can change with the browser window size). I would recommend going with the image option if you don't want the edge to look too sharp.

Comment: see the answer from Matt Coughlin - it's a very nice method

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A solution that doesn't require CSS3 support:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/UYRFY/) demo

HTML

```
<div class="shape">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.shape {
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.top {
    height:0;
    border-width:0 0 150px 400px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent #d71f55 #d71f55 transparent;
}
.bottom {
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#d71f55;
}

/* Support transparent border colors in IE6. */
* html .top {
    filter:chroma(color=#123456);
    border-top-color:#123456;
    border-left-color:#123456;
}
```

**Note:** You sometimes get excessive antialiasing of the diagonal in some browsers (like an exagerated blur or dropshadow). This trick can be a little unpredictable on modern browsers.

Comment: +1 for using the border triangle method - saw this a long time ago in some javascript + css/dom 3d demo. nice!

Comment: For a couple demos of this trick, see: http://www.forestpath.org/apps/webmotion/css-fg/animation.html?test=polygons and http://www.forestpath.org/apps/webmotion/css-fg/animation.html?test=show-right-triangles

Comment: ta for the link - again +1 ;)

Comment: It works nicely, much simpler than I thought, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've create a extended (and a Sass) version of Matt Coughlins greate answer, [I published it in my blog (german)](https://www.jumplink.eu/blog/post/diagonal-linien-reinem-css-sass-fur-schrage-layouts) and forked his [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1paf1sj8/4/).

**HTML**

```html
<div class="diagonal-shape bl-to-tr"></div>
<div class="block">Diagonal Shape</div>
<div class="diagonal-shape tr-to-bl"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="diagonal-shape tl-to-br"></div>
<div class="block">block2</div>
<div class="diagonal-shape br-to-tl"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
/**
 * Draw a diagonal shape, e.g. as diagonal segregation
 * 
 * @author: Matt Coughlin, Pascal Garber
 *
 * @param $color: The color of the shape, default #d71f55
 * @param $direction:
 *  bl-to-tr for bottom-left to top right
 *  tr-to-bl for top-right to bottom left
 *  tl-to-br for top-left to bottom right
 *  br-to-tl for bottom-right to top left
 * @param $height: The height of the shape, default 100px
 * @param $width: The width of the shape, default 100vw
 * @param $color: The color of the shape, default #d71f55
 *
 * @see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11074735/1465919
 */
.diagonal-shape.bl-to-tr {
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 100px 100vw;
  border-color: transparent #d71f55 #d71f55 transparent;
}
.diagonal-shape.tr-to-bl {
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px 100vw 0 0;
  border-color: #d71f55 transparent transparent #d71f55;
}
.diagonal-shape.tl-to-br {
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 100vw 100px 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent #d71f55 #d71f55;
}
.diagonal-shape.br-to-tl {
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px 0 0 100vw;
  border-color: #d71f55 #d71f55 transparent transparent;
}

.block {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    background-color: #d71f55;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

}

/* Support transparent border colors in IE6. */
* html .top {
    filter:chroma(color=#123456);
    border-top-color:#123456;
    border-left-color:#123456;
}
```

**SCSS**

```
/**
 * Draw a diagonal shape, e.g. as diagonal segregation
 * 
 * @author: Matt Coughlin, Pascal Garber
 *
 * @param $color: The color of the shape, default #d71f55
 * @param $direction:
 *  bl-to-tr for bottom-left to top right
 *  tr-to-bl for top-right to bottom left
 *  tl-to-br for top-left to bottom right
 *  br-to-tl for bottom-right to top left
 * @param $height: The height of the shape, default 100px
 * @param $width: The width of the shape, default 100vw
 * @param $color: The color of the shape, default #d71f55
 *
 * @see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11074735/1465919
 */
@mixin diagonal-shape($color: #d71f55, $direction: 'bl-to-tr', $height: 100px, $width: 100vw) {
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;

    @if $direction == 'bl-to-tr' {
        border-width: 0 0 $height $width;
        border-color: transparent $color $color transparent;
    } @else if $direction == 'tr-to-bl' {
        border-width: $height $width 0 0;
        border-color: $color transparent transparent $color;
    } @else if $direction == 'tl-to-br' {
        border-width: 0 $width $height 0;
        border-color: transparent  transparent $color $color;
    } @else if $direction == 'br-to-tl' {
        border-width: $height 0 0 $width;
        border-color: $color $color transparent  transparent ;
    }
}

.diagonal-shape {
    &.bl-to-tr {
        @include diagonal-shape($brand-primary, 'bl-to-tr');
    }
    &.tr-to-bl {
        @include diagonal-shape($brand-primary, 'tr-to-bl');
    }
    &.tl-to-br {
        @include diagonal-shape($brand-primary, 'tl-to-br');
    }
    &.br-to-tl {
        @include diagonal-shape($brand-primary, 'br-to-tl');
    }
}
```

With the SCSS Mixin you can easily create you own classes:

```scss
.your-claas {
    @include diagonal-shape($color, $direction, $height, $width);
}
```