# Wedge shaped menu

Tags: html, css

I've been digging into how to create a wedge shaped menu and came across the following stackoverflow post: [Diagonal Wedge Shaped CSS - Edge to Edge Centered in Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074601/diagonal-wedge-shaped-css-edge-to-edge-centered-in-browser)

I've re-purposed the example image Varazi drew up to better explain my own situation (please excuse the old writing on it). I've added 2 menu items, home and contact, to show what I'm trying.
[image]

The code I have been playing around with (found from the above link).

*HTML*

```
<div class="shape">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.shape {
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.top {
    height:0;
    border-width:0 0 150px 400px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent #d71f55 #d71f55 transparent;
}
.bottom {
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#d71f55;
}

/* Support transparent border colors in IE6. */
* html .top {
    filter:chroma(color=#123456);
    border-top-color:#123456;
    border-left-color:#123456;
}
```

---

**Update:** After playing quite a lot with it, really fun challenge I must say, I have finally gotten it exactly the way I needed it to be with the helpful tip by *Talkingrock* (thanks man!). My remaining challenge would be showing the `.sub-menu` inside an `overflow: hidden` element (`#masthead`), but it's not overly important as I can have the links plastered on the homepage in the relevant content sections.

Hope the below code helps a poor soul out, such as myself, who needed help. Enjoy! :)

*HTML* (I'm using WordPress/Bootstrap)

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://demo.dev/" title="demo" rel="home">
                    <img width="159" height="134" src="http://demo.dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="http://demo.dev/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://demo.dev/us/">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://demo.dev/services/">Services</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://demo.dev/industrial-electrical/">Industrial Electrical</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://demo.dev/commercial-electrical/">Commercial Electrical</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://demo.dev/domestic-electrical/">Domestic Electrical</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://demo.dev/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header>
```

*CSS* (using Less)

```
/* --- header */

#masthead {
        overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
        bottom: 50px; height: 200px;
    background: red;
    transform: skew(0deg, -3deg);
}

/* --- main navigation */

#site-navigation {
    position: relative;
        bottom: -50px;
    height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: none;
        border: none;
    transform: skew(0deg, 3deg);

    .container,
    .navbar-collapse {
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    .nav {
        height: 100%;

        &>li {
            height: 100%;

            &>a {
                height: 100%;
                    padding: 80px 15px 0;
                color: #fff;
            }
            &.current-menu-item,
            &:hover {
                &>a {
                    background-color: @tree-poppy;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update2:** Just wanted to quickly mention you can also attach the wedge part to an existing element easily without using any additional elements as well!

*CSS*

```
#masthead:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
        top: -45px; left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    width: 100%; height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: skew(0deg, -3deg);
}
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code, perhaps via jsfiddle (or similar).

Comment: I came across a live example of this layout today, complete with the menu items, that you may be interested in. Its located at www.1and1.com. They use an absolutely positioned, skewed div to cover the bottom of the header area. It has the standard div settings that would vary with your design like top and left, and height and width. The key styles are background-color:#ffffff (set to match the color of the website background); and transform:skew(0deg, -3deg); to create the angle.

Comment: @Talkingrock Hi and thank you for the tip! In the end that's what I ended up doing myself because it was the only thing that worked across all devices. Again thanks friend! :)

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution to this interesting question:) I tried using borders on a div to create the triangle shaped white wedge, but it was messy and needed overflow hidden on the container (less than a great idea when a menu is involved). I also created several colored skewed divs at different angles, and used a z-index to layer them in front of and behind the menu items for a cool effect.

Comment: That's smart, you skewed #masthead. Here's the JSFiddle where the skewed div was absolutely positioned at the bottom, and z-indexes were used for layering. http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/eu7txndg/

Comment: @Talkingrock Love your menu! I borrowed Brandon's method in skewing the main element and then countering the skew on the child element (in my case being the navigation menu). I was thinking roughly the same thing whereby I would stack another wedge element to hide the full height nav, but that would have killed the submenus I had on it. I ended up giving each anchor it's own mini wedge and moved them into place haha

Comment: I tried to skew the header div because that would be one less element, but it skewed everything inside and I couldn't find a good fix. (didn't think about counter skewing:) That's when I used www.1and1.com's idea of designing the header as usual, and adding the skewed div as decoration at the bottom. This is defiantly a fun question, and I learned some new stuff. I looked at it in IE9, and it displayed the divs as usual, without the skew. JSFiddle doesn't work in IE8 or older.

Comment: @Talkingrock I'd be completely surprised, shocked and stunned all at once if it did work on IE8 or older, but then again those browsers shouldn't deserve the time of day ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

The HTML:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#" class="link-1">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="link-2">Contact</a>
    <a href="#" class="link-3">About</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The CSS:

```
header {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -550px;
  height: 850px;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

nav {
  width: 120%;
  margin: 0 -10%;
  transform: rotate(-12deg);
  background: red;
  padding: 0 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(12deg);
  background: purple;
  padding-top: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: -900px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.link-1 {
  top: -36px;
}

.link-2 {
  top: -18px;
}
```

Here's a working example: http://codepen.io/btpoe/pen/GavLk

Please note that this would not work in IE8 or less and would need some sort of fallback.

Comment: Hi Brandon, thank you very much for your answer! I'm just tweaking it to see if I can match it to the above, but you've put me on the right track :)